# Sending the current displayed index of item in QComboBox at start up

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots, qcombobox

Using `signal and slots` method to get index and text of selected items in `QcomboBox` is well known. The code below is an illustration of that. But how can I tell my code to recieve and send the first display item at startup, Methods like `Activated, currentIndexChanged, Highlighted` only work by dropdown `QCombobox`.

[image]

**Output:**

```
1
item2
2
item3
```

**The sample code:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(combo)
        combo.addItems(["item1", "item2", "item3"])
        combo.setMinimumWidth(150)
        combo.activated[int].connect(self.onActivatedIndex)
        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivatedText)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onActivatedIndex(self, index):
        print(index)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onActivatedText(self, text):
        print(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your own custom signal and emit that in the `__init__` section of your object. This signal could then access the first item in the `QComboBox`. Another method could be to use a singleShot timer but making a custom signal would probably be better. You can retrieve the current index with `currentIndex()` or `currentText()`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    startup = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.combo)
        self.combo.addItems(["item1", "item2", "item3"])
        self.combo.setMinimumWidth(150)
        self.combo.activated[int].connect(self.onActivatedIndex)
        self.combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivatedText)

        self.startup.connect(self.current_index)
        self.startup.emit()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def current_index(self):
        print(self.combo.currentIndex())
        print(self.combo.currentText())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onActivatedIndex(self, index):
        print(index)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onActivatedText(self, text):
        print(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.combo)
        self.combo.addItems(["item1", "item2", "item3"])
        self.combo.setMinimumWidth(150)

        self.combo.activated[int].connect(self.onActivatedIndex)
        self.combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivatedText)

        self.combo.activated.emit(1)                           # <---

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onActivatedIndex(self, index):
        print("\nindex->", index)
        print("text ->", self.combo.itemText(index))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onActivatedText(self, text):
        print(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```